# How to Build a listView that load more data when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of my class  WorkOrder. This ArrayList this populating a ListView, however, when my SELECT returns a very large result, I have problems to fill the listView. Curious somehow load the information as my need. When searching, I found some ways to use using setOnScrollListener event, but it was unclear how the information is uploaded to the listView. 
My doubts are:

- How do I load the information? They must be requested from the server as needed or we fill the entire ArrayList and do a control later?
- Where can I find a simple tutorial for my need?

To fill my listView, I use the following code:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pending_wos);
    new LoadPendingWorkOrders().execute();
    }

    private class LoadPendingWorkOrders extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progress = ProgressDialog.show(PendingWorkOrders.this,
                getResources().getString(R.string.Wait), getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.LoadingPendingWOs));
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            worker = Application.getInstance().getUser();

            WorkOrderQueries woQ = WorkOrderQueriesFactory
                    .createWorkOrderQueriesFactory();

            pendingWorkOrders = woQ
                    .selectPendingWorkOrders(asset, fromDate, workType,
                            workRequestType, workOrderState);

                for (WorkOrder w : pendingWorkOrders) {
                    if (w.getDataCompare() >= 0) {
                        w.setFlag(getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.green));
                    } else {
                        w.setFlag(getResources()
                                .getDrawable(R.drawable.red));
                    }
                }

        } catch (QueryException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        setListAdapter(new PendingWOArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.pending_wos_list, pendingWorkOrders));

        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        if (progress != null)
            progress.dismiss();

    }
    }
```

this is my adapter class:

```
public class PendingWOArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WorkOrder> {

private List<WorkOrder> workOrders = new ArrayList<WorkOrder>();

public PendingWOArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<WorkOrder> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.workOrders = objects;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected ImageView flagIcon;
    protected TextView workOrderName;
    protected TextView workOrderState;
    protected TextView priority;
    protected TextView plannedDate;
    protected TextView asset;
    protected CheckBox chkDownloadWorkOrder;
}

public int getCount() {
    return this.workOrders.size();
}

public WorkOrder getItem(int index) {
    return this.workOrders.get(index);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    WorkOrder pendingWO = getItem(position);

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pending_wos_list, parent, false);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.flagIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.flagIcon);
        viewHolder.workOrderName = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.TxtWorkOrder);
        viewHolder.workOrderState = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.TxtWorkOrderState);
        viewHolder.priority = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.TxtPriority);
        viewHolder.plannedDate = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.TxtPlannedDate);
        viewHolder.asset = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.TxtAsset);
        viewHolder.chkDownloadWorkOrder = (CheckBox) row
                .findViewById(R.id.ChkDownloadWorkOrder);

        viewHolder.chkDownloadWorkOrder
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        WorkOrder workOrder = (WorkOrder) viewHolder.chkDownloadWorkOrder
                                .getTag();
                        workOrder.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                    }
                });

        row.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.chkDownloadWorkOrder.setTag(pendingWO);
    } else {
        ((ViewHolder) row.getTag()).chkDownloadWorkOrder.setTag(workOrders
                .get(position));
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    holder.workOrderName.setText(pendingWO.toString());
    holder.workOrderState.setText("Estado OS: " + pendingWO.getWorkOrderState() + " - "
            + pendingWO.getWorkOrderStateName());
    holder.priority.setText("Prioridade: " + pendingWO.getPriority());
    holder.plannedDate.setText("Data Prevista: "
            + pendingWO.getPlannedDate());
    holder.asset.setText("Ativo: " + pendingWO.getAsset() + " - "
            + pendingWO.getAssetName());
    holder.flagIcon.setImageDrawable(pendingWO.getFlag());
    holder.chkDownloadWorkOrder.setChecked(pendingWO.isSelected());

    if (pendingWO.isChkVisible()) {
        holder.chkDownloadWorkOrder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.chkDownloadWorkOrder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return row;
}
```

}

Comment: Can we see the code for your adapter?

Comment: I just edit and add my adpter to questioning

Comment: Your code looks fine, what's the problem?

Comment: Everything is working, but when my pendingWorkOrders list is very large, I have problems loading my complete listView. I would like some solution to carry it in stages, where the user would request using setOnScrollListener event. I even find some stuff online, but not helped me much.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the size of this list is too big to keep in memory without loss of performance. I would consider using a `CursorAdapter`, it is a better and cleaner solution to your problem, in my opinion.

Two good tutorials:

1. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_4_-_using_cursoradapters/
2. http://www.gustekdev.com/2013/05/custom-cursoradapter-and-why-not-use.html

Comment: No. .. it ends up changing my purpose. I need a way I can do this using ArrayList ();